# Scaling argument for friction force on a chain in shear flow

Tags: fluid-dynamics, flow, viscosity, polymers

In her paper entitled "Deformations of One Tethered Chain in Strong Flows", the author makes the argument that given a shear flow velocity $v_x(y)=sy$ in a solution of viscosity $\eta$, and a tethered particle in the flow of size $y$, then the friction force felt by the particle is $f=\eta sy^2$ (ignoring numerical pre-factors). If we have a chain of such particles tethered together in a line of varying sizes $y_i$, then the total force on the chain is $
\sum_i \eta sy_i^2$. So far so good.

Now the author transitions to a continuum, so that our blob sizes vary continuously as $y(x)$, She then says that $\sum_i \eta sy_i^2\approx \int \eta s y(x) dx$. Can someone shed some light on how that transition is made? I'm sure it's simple, but I'm not seeing it.
[image]

EDIT: is it just that the line density of particles is $y^{-1}$, so we divide by the density when moving to the integral?

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by "tethered particle". Then you speak of "blob". What is the connection? It would help if you could provide a bit more context (don't worry about length of question), and if possible include a schematic figure as well.

Comment: A polymer is typically modeled as a connected series of blobs of monomers, with the blob size dictated by interactions. In this case, the blob scale is set by the pulling force as y=kT/f. I did use both terms to mean the same thing in the question, my mistake. I will add a schematic. The blobs are indicated by circles, which are treated as solid units for shear flow viscosity. The tether refers to the fact that one end is fixed to a hard surface, while the other is free to adjust in the flow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the continuum limit the body (i.e. aggregate of blobs) seems to become a cylinder, but with increasing radius along X direction. Area of elemental circular strip at distance $x$ will be (circumference of cylinder at $x)\times~dx$. But circumference is proportional to diameter $y(x)$. Therefore area of the elementary strip at $x$ is $\sim y(x)~dx$. Shear force on this cylindrical strip is product of shear stress ($\sim \eta s$) and its area.